# Is there any way to associate two types to allow generic methods to return a related type based on the type of the input parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a generic expander extension method that will operate on a collection of database object, and convert them and all selected sub-models to internal model objects.
I know EF can help with this, but not as it's currently used in the rest of the codebase I'm working with, and that's not the question anyway.

The question is: Is there any way to couple classes so generics will know if one is used, the other is implied as it's pair?

To explain...

I want to have a method

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ExpandAsModels<TSource,TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
```

that will handle type binding successfully so I don't have to fill in the template values every time.
i.e. instead of

```
var result = datasource.ExpandAsModel<DBCarObject,CarModel>();
```

I want to be able to use

```
var result = datasource.ExpandAsModel();
```

I know this sounds pedantic but I'm trying to produce code that junior coders won't stuff up. 
What I want is to be able to associate SourceTypes and ResultTypes.  For example, having an explicit association between DBCarObject and CarModel.

I tried doing this by making DBCarObject implement an `interface IDBObject<CarModel>` and defining the extension method as

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ExpandAsModels<TSource,TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
                                        where TSource: IDBObject<TResult>
```

This works in that it prevents mismatched objects, but it doesn't automatch the generics (so you can't use the simple `var result = datasource.ExpandAsModel();` form of call)

Can anyone explain if there is a way to do this?
There seem to be so many situations where types operate in related ways that could make use of this sort of association.

If I were designing C# I guess I'd be after a feature that might be used like...

```
class a {}
class b {}
class x {
    associated a mymodel;
}
class y {
    associated b mymodel;
}

TResult doSomething<TResult,TSource>(TSource data) 
             where TSource has association mymodel
             where TResult : mymodel
```

This would then require that TSource was an object that had an association called mymodel
and that TResult would be of the type of mymodel define by the association.

The final result would be that `doSomething(new x());` would have a return type of a and `doSomething(new y());` would have a return type of b.

Either that, or have the compiler able to trace through generics as per my example above.

Comment: Can't you simplify the extension method to `public static IEnumerable<TResult> ExpandAsModels<TResult>(this IQueryable<IDBObject<TResult>> source)`?

Answer (score 2):

If you drop `TSource` from your extension method, the compiler can deduce the type arguments;

```cs
        public interface IDBObject<TResult>
        {
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TResult> ExpandAsModels<TResult>(this IQueryable<IDBObject<TResult>> source)
        {
            // TODO
        }

        public class ClientView { 
        }

        public class Client : IDBObject<ClientView>
        {
        }

        public static void Test() {
            IQueryable<Client> query = null;
            var result = query.ExpandAsModels();
        }
```

If you need your extension method to have convenient access to the type `TSource`, you could make your generic interface recursive;

```cs
        public interface IDBObject<TSource, TResult> where TSource : IDBObject<TSource, TResult>
        {
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TResult> ExpandAsModels<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<IDBObject<TSource, TResult>> source) where TSource : IDBObject<TSource, TResult>
        {
            // TODO
        }

        public class Client : IDBObject<Client, ClientView>
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
public abstract class SourceBase<TResult> where TResult : TargetBase
    {
        public abstract TResult MapToResult();
    }

    public class TargetBase
    {
    }


    public class SourceA : SourceBase<TargetA>
    {
        public string SourceProperty { get; set; }
        public override TargetA MapToResult()
        {
             // here maps the data to target;
            var data = new TargetA();
            data.TargetProperty = this.SourceProperty;
            return data;
        }
    }

    public class TargetA : TargetBase
    {
        public string TargetProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

The extension:

```
     public static TargetBase ExpandAsModels<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source) where TSource : SourceA, new()
    {
        TSource data = new TSource();
        // fill the data reading from db 

        // Maps and return the value
        return data.MapToResult();
    }
```

When use:

```
IQueryable<SourceA> MySourceData = ...
MySourceData.ExpandAsModels();
```